# Which mnemonic generators exist or existed?

Tags: mnemonic

I am unable to open a wallet I created roughly 2 years ago. 
In that time I have been using MEW, MetaMask and something that I installed locally on Window, which I forgot the name of. Not sure which wallet actually generated the mnemonic, however MetaMask support claims it is probably not it.

The mnemonic phrase was stored in LastPass and LastPass has no history of any changes to it, so I believe it should be correct.
I've tried to create the wallet with MetaMask, MEW and MyCrypto, but none worked.

One word in an arbitrary position is "rebound".

Checking the [BIP39 wordlist](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt) my mnemonic doesn't match any word, which gives me an impression that the phrase was generated with another algorithm/word list.

With what algorithm could the mnemoinic be generated?
Can we have a list of all of them here for others with similar issues?

----EDIT----

The mnemonic phrase is 12 words long.
I've never owned or used a hardware wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how far your technical skills reach, but I found a script in one of my repositories from 2016. Maybe it was a more simple implementation, like one of the following?

```
var ethUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
const Wallet = require("ethereumjs-wallet");
var thirdparty = require('ethereumjs-wallet/thirdparty')


exports.fromParityPhrase = function (phrase) {
    var hash = ethUtil.sha3(new Buffer(phrase));
    for (var i = 0; i < 16384; i++) {
        hash = ethUtil.sha3(hash);
    }while (ethUtil.privateToAddress(hash)[0] != 0) {
        hash = ethUtil.sha3(hash);
    }return new Wallet(hash);
};

exports.fromPrivateKey = function(privateKey) {
    return Wallet.fromPrivateKey(privateKey);
}

exports.fromEthercamp = function(phrase) {
  return thirdparty.fromEtherCamp(phrase);
}
```

Ethercamp and parity used to have a less strict way of generating the hashes.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer as it is more versatile. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have a stab at this...

It'll be a wallet that supports [SLIP-0039](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0039.md) (Shamir's Secret-Sharing for Mnemonic Codes), the [word list](https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0039/wordlist.txt) for which includes "rebound".

I believe Trezors use such a scheme, so if you have a Trezor - or did have - that's where it'll have come from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it does not seem to be. I've edited the question to add additional information. It had to be a software wallet and only 1 of the 12 words match the word list "rebound". The others are not contained. Not sure if I can post additional words as it would be easier to bruteforce it. The address in question is 0x00c6ea84064e0db68bf36b61506bcd3f4a48de7b if it helps.

Comment: So none of the other 11 words are in the SLIP-0039 word list? That's annoying :-( Let me have another poke around...

Comment: (Trezor was just an example - it could have been a software wallet that implemented the SLIP-0039 standard. But apparently not if none of the other words match.)

Comment: Only 1 of the 12 words was in, the others were not. Is there a list/repository of all the possible mnemonic algorithms? I was unable to find anything other than BIP39. Would another word help?

Comment: No, don't worry about a second word - "rebound" is unusual enough as a search string. It wasn't anything related to diceware, was it? (e.g. The EFF's diceware wordlist for generating passphrases includes "rebound" - https://www.eff.org/files/2016/07/18/eff_large_wordlist.txt). The only other thing I can suggest to get this more exposure is to cross-post on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum. Someone must know...

Comment: No, dicewire doesn't ring a bell. I might have had installed Mist at some point so that might be the desktop wallet, but it seems it did not support mnemonic phrases. All words are in the EFF dictionary. What does that mean? Thank you, will post there.

Comment: Next try: Parity client? Here's the word list: https://github.com/paritytech/wordlist/blob/master/res/wordlist.txt (includes "rebound")

Comment: Thank you for the help. I upvoted your answer, however accepted the other one as it is more versatile.

Comment: Cool - no problem - glad you got something that works :-)